# Format print of list of objects

Tags: python, pprint

For example:

```
>>> pprint(response.choices)
[Choice(finish_reason='length', index=0, message=ChatCompletionMessage(content='The time complexity of the code is O(n * k), where n is the value of parameter n and k is the value of parameter k. This is because there are two nested loops, one iterating n times and the other iterating k times. The accum variable is incremented `n *', role='assistant', function_call=None, tool_calls=None))]
```

I try `print` and `pprint` and response is as above (other lists also the same). How can I print this in readable format (not in one line)?

Comment: `pprint` should already do that - "If _compact_ is false (the default) then each item of a sequence will be formatted on a separate line." And in fact "If _compact_ is true, as many items as will fit within the _width_ will be formatted on each output line." - as that defaults to 80, your ~400 character line shouldn't show up.

Comment: How are `Choice` and `ChatCompletionMessage` defined? Are they dataclasses, or just classes with a manually defined `__repr__`?

Comment: no mather for chatcomplketion messagae. Any list from openai is printed like above.
from openai reference ( but i cant print is like tis):
{
  "id": "chatcmpl-123",
  "object": "chat.completion",
  "created": 1677652288,
  "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo-0613",
  "system_fingerprint": "fp_44709d6fcb",
  "choices": [{
    "index": 0,
    "message": {
      "role": "assistant",
      "content": "\n\nHello there, how may I assist you today?",
    },
    "finish_reason": "stop"
  }],
  "usage": {
    "prompt_tokens": 9,
    "completion_tokens": 12,
    "total_tokens": 21
  }
}

Comment: Have you tried `for choice in response.choices: print(json.dumps(choice.__dict__, indent=4))`

Comment: don't work.
But srange if i copy code from any exampleon pages  i have it also in one line.

Comment: `print(*response.choices, sep='\n')`